# UIProgressView is not updating, but the title is

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

This one is a real head scratcher, I am using an operation queue like so:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
queue.addOperation {
    generator = BillGenerationv3(procedures: procedure)
        batchPrinting = true
        if generator!.generateBills(pInfo: pInfo, cInfo: cInfo, view: self) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct
            self.progressBar.progress = Float(count/uidPrecentage)
            self.title = "Batching Claims \(count)/\(uidPrecentage)...Please Wait"
            nextClaim()
        }                                
  }
}
```

It updates the title perfectly, yet the progress bar does nothing until the end. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `count` and `uidPrecentage`? Are they Floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let someInt: Int = 3
let someOtherInt: Int = 5
```

This will not work

```
print(Float(someInt/someOtherInt))

//"0.0"
```

This will

```
print(Float(someInt)/Float(someOtherInt))

//"0.6"
```

The reason being that in the first scenario you're initializing a Float with **the result of integer division** which causes the result to be rounded to an integer by the nature of the operation.

The second scenario involves explicitly **dividing two floating point numbers** so the result will therefore also be a float and handle decimal numbers.

Comment: Ive been dealing with this for an excessively long time what a poor oversight on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure your values `count` and `uidPrecentage` return valid ones (according to your estimations) and the calculus is *0 <= value <= 1*.

Last but certainly not least, you should be using the progress view's class method `setProgress(_ progress: Float, animated: Bool)` to update it instead of modifying directly the variable. As seen in the official documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview/1619846-setprogress, it even hands you for free the progress animation should you want

Comment: The reason I switched to the way I had it in the question is I thought perhaps the set progress was interfering with updating. Thee issue was the ints were being rounded as the accepted solution, but thanks!